# Understanding MDN function syntax using Function.prototype.call as an example

Tags: javascript

Using this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) as an example, I want to understand entirely the syntax MDN uses here:

[image]

I know that things in brackets are 'optional'.
Does `...argN` generally mean unlimited amount of arguments?
Why are the brackets and commas written on the wrong side of each other? Wouldn't it be better if it were just:
`func.call([thisArg], [arg1], [arg2], [...argN])`?

Answer (score 0):

No, an optional number of parameters are usually written as `[arg1, arg2, ...argN]`. You are not passing a number of parameters which have distinct valid values (to disambiguate) and are all optional.